# Which Australian bank/account incurs lowest fees using an ATM card overseas?

Tags: budget, money, australia, payment-cards, atms

As per [this question about US banks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/us-debit-atm-card-with-lowest-fees-for-travel), I would like to know if any Australian bank offers an account with an ATM card (or Visa/Mastercard debit card) with no or low fees for travellers using them in foreign cash machines.

This includes whether certain Australian banks have deals with certain other banks in other countries where fees are waived/reduced.

My current bank account seems to have too many and too high fees when I'm travelling. If there's a better one I may change banks when I get home.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is now out of date, since 28 degrees changed their T&Cs on precisely this issue in 2014. The use (without foreign transaction fees) of the card for purchases remains unchanged. Original answer follows.

[28 Degrees offers a Mastercard (credit card) that doesn't charge international fees.](http://www.28degreescard.com.au/) If you put your card into credit and just withdraw your own money, you won't be charged cash advance fees.
But if you withdraw their money, you get charged at credit card interest rates until it is repaid. It's a way of avoiding the fees charged by the Australian banks when travelling abroad, but you might still get charged withdrawal fees by the local bank responsible for the ATM.

Comment: What about the percentage charged when I withdraw overseas? That always seemed to be my bank charging it rather than the local one.

Comment: Be warned that it's run by GE Money.

Comment: @nathanchere What do you mean? Why would this be something to warn about?

Answer (score 8):

**NAB** [currently charge](http://www.nab.com.au/wps/wcm/connect/nab/nab/home/personal_finance/15/8#sect2) a fee of $4 plus 2% on foreign cash withdrawls, and 2% on foreign transactions (other than cash withdrawls). However, if you have a NAB Gold account (which has a [monthly fee](http://www.nab.com.au/wps/wcm/connect/nab/nab/home/personal_finance/5/1/3) unless you pay in a lot each month), then there are no foreign transaction fees (including no fees on foreign cash withdrawls). So, if you want to take money out abroad more than about 25 times a year, it's worth going for their Gold account.

A normal **St George's** account [currently charges](http://www.stgeorge.com.au/personal/bank-accounts/transaction-accounts/complete-freedom) $5 plus 3% on overseas cash withdrawls, and 3% on foreign transactions, so NAB looks cheap... **Commonwealth Bank** [charge](http://www.commbank.com.au/personal/accounts/everyday-account/rates-fees/default.aspx) a similar $5+3% / 3% fee structure, though they do have a cheaper rate of $2+3% on certain ATMs in New Zealand, Indonesia and Vietnam. **Westpac** also [charge](http://www.westpac.com.au/personal-banking/services/overseas-services/using-atms-overseas/) $5+3% / 3%, but they have a [larger list](http://www.westpac.com.au/personal-banking/services/overseas-services/using-atms-overseas/) of countries where the ATM from a particular bank will avoid you the $5 fee (but not the 3%).

Looks like there isn't a really obvious choice, unless you pay enough in every month to get one of the premium accounts for free. Well, unless you can talk NAB into letting you only pay for a Gold account for only the time you're away!

Comment: Excellent answer @Gagravarr! You only left out my current bank, ANZ. I know they are in the same ballpark ±$1 ±1%. Do you know the amount of NAB's monthly fee?

Comment: I linked to their Gold Account page so you can check the details, but it's currently $10/month unless you pay in at least $5,000/month

Comment: Even $10/month is two international withdrawals a month not including the percentage...

Comment: Or probably about 25/year including it, hence that bit of the answer :) Guess it depends exactly how often you're away if it makes sense or not

Comment: Also I wonder about the expense of changing accounts. I try to be home for half a year then travel half a year so such an account would be a loss for the half year I spend at home but a gain for the half I spend travelling.

Comment: You do get a few extra bits on top of the no foreign fees part, might be worth you looking through their site and see if any of the other NAB Gold benefits are useful to you. Either way, you have the info now, so you can weight it up and decide!

Answer (score 4):

Citibank have an account now that has no ATM withdrawal fees for foreign banks. The ATM themselves may charge you, but Citibank won't. This seems a good replacement for the old 28degrees card. Note that this is a savings card so you need to have transferred money onto it before you can use it.

Comment: Yep. Citibank is currently the one card you want to use. No fees, very little drawbacks.

Haven't paid a cent whilst being 6 months overseas on this card.

Comment: Is there an annual fee or a minimum balance required for the account? Many years ago when Cirrus (or Plus?) first appeared I got a Citibank account because they were the first in Australia to have it, but I needed $10,000 minimum balance and had to pay a regular fee once my account went below that. Are there any relevant rules such as those that we should know about?

Comment: There are no annual fees on this card. 

The two minor drawbacks are that you need to pre-load the card (it is not a credit card), and the substandard customer service and internet banking/apps that citibank in Australia have. In spite of this it is still the best option.