# Which US credit cards have the cheapest foreign transaction fees?

Tags: budget, international-travel, payment-cards, fees-and-charges

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [US debit/ATM card with lowest fees for travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/us-debit-atm-card-with-lowest-fees-for-travel)
>   [When traveling to a country with a different currency, how should you take your money?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your-m)
>   [How can Americans get a chip-and-pin credit card for use while abroad?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3203/how-can-americans-get-a-chip-and-pin-credit-card-for-use-while-abroad)

I'm going to a foreign country from the USA. Which is the best credit card to take along to minimize fees?

Comment: Which question is the "exact duplicate"?

Comment: Is it common practice to downvote duplicates, or are the downvotes reflective of the question's quality?

Answer (score 2):

As well as forgein transaction fees, remember that some credit cards that are common in USA might not be commonly accepted in the rest of the world. In Iran, no US credit cards are accepted, in Ireland, American Express is rarely accepted (but Visa & Mastercard are), in Eastern Africa (Kenya & Tanzania) Visa is very commonly accepted, but Mastercard is less commonly accepted.

So you should narrow down your question and tell us where you're going and what kind of credit/debit card(s) you have. e.g. "I'm going to $COUNTRY, will my $CREDIT_CARD_BRAND work?"

Comment: Credit card fees are charged by the card issuer and don't change for different countries. A separate question could be "Which credit card is most accept world-wide or for a particular region or country."

Answer (score 1):

The only major American credit card I'm aware of that doesn't charge foreign transaction fees is Capital One.