# Getting cash in Israel (least expensive way)

Tags: money, israel

What is the least expensive way for an American tourist in Israel to get cash?

The options seem to be:

Debit card - but there are withdrawal fees, often 5% or more.

Credit card - but interest starts immediately when taking out cash, yet one month fee may be less than the debit card fee

Carry cash - but there is a conversion fee when changing into local currency.

What are the options to minimize fees?

Note: This question was asked in more general terms in 2011 and some relevant information is available in that question [US debit/ATM card with lowest fees for travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/us-debit-atm-card-with-lowest-fees-for-travel). But even in 2011 the answer was too general, not naming specific banks or credit cards.  Also, I am specifically asking about Israel, not the world, and about 2016, not 2011.  So I am asking that the question be reopened.

Comment: There are credit cards that don't charge conversion fees.

Comment: @JonathanReez That answer is quite general. I would like information specific to Israel.

Comment: @Karlson  I've heard of conversion fees on purchases. Are there conversion fees on cash withdrawals as well?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC Israel is a first-world country, so the general answer works

Comment: @yehuda_nyc Depends.  There may be interbank agreement that don't charge ATM fees.

Comment: @JonathanReez  Also, " get a debit card (or failing that a credit card) with low/no foreign transaction and cash withdrawl fees. (In the UK, the Halifax Clarity Card " does not provide much specific guidance for an American.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC we have a separate questions about that very topic :) http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/us-debit-atm-card-with-lowest-fees-for-travel

Comment: @JonathanReez  This relevant page dates back to 2011. I am looking for current information.