# Least expensive way for a tourist to get cash in Israel?

Tags: money, israel

What is the least expensive way for an American tourist in Israel to get cash?

The options seem to be:

Debit card - but there are withdrawal fees, often 5% or more.

Credit card - but interest starts immediately when taking out cash, yet one month fee may be less than the debit card fee

Carry cash - but there is a conversion fee when changing into local currency.

What are the best options to minimize fees?

Comment: ATMs are everywhere in Israel, and most (although not all) of them work fine with US cards.  Even if there is a fee, debit cards are still almost always the cheapest option.

Comment: Or also http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/67581/7657