# Prepaid debit card for use in Morocco, obtained in United States

Tags: payment-cards, morocco, forex-cards

I see that [Travelex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelex) now offers a prepaid [*Travelex Money Card*](https://www.travelex.com/travel-money-card) with a locked-in exchange rate and generally no further fees such as for ATM withdrawal. Unfortunately, they do not offer [Moroccan dirham (MAD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moroccan_dirham) money for [Morocco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morocco).

Are there alternatives for a US citizen to obtain before departing to Morocco? Are there other prepaid debit cards that could be purchased in the US but used in Morocco for ATM cash withdrawal and charge-card usage, with a somewhat reasonable set of fees and exchange rate for MAD?

Comment: I need to buy a prepaid Visa card that I can use in Casablanca, Morrison. Can you help me with this? If I purchase today can I get it by Thursday?

Answer (score 3):

There are strong restrictions on taking MAD out of the country, so I believe technically you should not be able to buy/sell Dirhams outside the country, and thus there'd be no way to get locked-in exchange rates.

So just rely on any international card with low fees, refer [US debit/ATM card with lowest fees for travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/us-debit-atm-card-with-lowest-fees-for-travel)