How to check for ATM fees when traveling?
Using an ATM abroad might incur three different fees:

Currency exchange fee.

A fee levied by your bank for using your card abroad.

A fee levied by the ATM operator.


The first two are very easy to check (and avoid). I'm only struggling to find out whether the 3rd one will be charged and how much.
The only (mostly) reliable way to check it is to find an actual ATM, proceed with a withdrawal and wait for the machine to display (or not) a fee that will be charged. Usually, using ATMs next to bank branches is free.
However, this is not always the case. For example in Turkey and Rwanda I could withdraw for free at a bank, and with a fee of around 5 USD at another. And I couldn't find any info online in advance about that. In The Netherlands withdrawals from the big 4 banks would usually be free, and boutique ATMs like GWK and Euronet will charge over 5 Euros.
I wonder if there's a map to check for this, instead of doing a deep search for every country I travel to. I'm surprised VISA and MasterCard haven't come up with a solution like this already, or have they?

(+1) Just for completeness if someone else is interested in following your advice: In the Netherlands, retail banks have been aggressively closing branches and do not operate separate ATM networks anymore. Instead, they got together to set up something called “Geldmaat” (bright yellow ATMs) but they work similarly (no fees for withdrawals with a card from elsewhere in the EU, not sure beyond that).

Another option is to get a debit card that reimburses ATM fees, so you don't have to care. Charles Schwabe Investor Checking does this, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/ for more details.

Card limits to the rescue (if you have an internet connection)
Our strategy is to set a limit on the card so that we can at most withdraw the amount we intend to withdraw. We typically use Revolut whilst abroad, so I will just put all the money I don't intend to withdraw into a 'pocket' or 'vault' or whatever they call it now (imagine a savings account without interest, the point is that you can't access it by paying with your card). Typically this means that I will have exactly 200 euros available at the start (as that's the monthly free withdrawal limit ).
Then I go to the ATM, and try to withdraw exactly 200 euros. If a fee is mentioned - and I deem the fee acceptable - I will adjust the amount I try to withdraw downwards. If a maximum withdrawal is mentioned, I adjust the amount available on the card before actually trying the withdrawal.
The point is that if there is an unadvertised fee (something I have seen only a handful of times in the last 3 years (25 countries or so)) this will cause the withdrawal to fail, and it will show me the fee by looking at the failed withdrawal notification.
Once with an ATM that felt shady (it was a tourist focused ATM, and it didn't ask whether we wanted to convert or not) we even just tried to withdraw whilst we intentionally had 0 euros on our card, to check whether it wouldn't do something weird (it did, so we ended up not using it).
Online research
In general the online communities of 'travel banks' (like the Revolut forums) are amazing places to find advice for ATMs that don't charge withdrawal fees (to be fair, these lists are often outdated and/or not completely accurate (e.g. in some countries visa cards might be charged whilst mastercards might not be on the same ATM), but they are amazing starting points). I will typically try to find a dedicated thread about a country I am travelling to, but here is for example one attempt to collect everything into a single spreadsheet: https://community.revolut.com/t/the-ultimate-free-atm-list-travelling-by-country/61491 (For example in that same thread someone mentions that in Rwanda I&M bank doesn't charge for a VISA card in 2019). Of course, this is more likely to be accurate if you use Revolut as well, but as a starting to point to figure out which ATMs to check out it's absolutely perfect no matter what.

I'm afraid that, as it stands, you will have to do your 'deep search'.
The cost, levied by the ATM operator, can depend on your bank, your type of card, your country, the country you are withdrawing money in, and the bank/operator the ATM belongs to.
So, any exhaustive map that would allow you to look this up, would have to take into account who is doing the searching. Not impossible, of course, but quite a bit of work. And, yeah, I'm convinced there would be a market for a service that would provide this information.
fwiw, I'm finding that, over the last few years, it has become easier to pay in many stores with foreign debit cards, for which transaction fees (but not exchange fees) tend to be low or zero.

Note that some banks, if they like you enough (read: if you have deposited enough money and the bank feels like offering it as a perk), will not only waive ATM fees on their own ATMs, but will also reimburse you for third-party ATM fees (up to some reasonable limit, one presumes).

ATMs belong to their operators, who need to make money from operating them. ATMs require quite an expensive set up: money transfer services, secured connection to the processing networks, physical security to avoid thefts and burglaries, handling breakdowns and issues. All these cost money, and the ATM fees are to pay for that.
Usually, the fees are published at or close to the ATM (stickers, or on screen as part of the withdrawal process). Different countries have different rules, so you should research your destination country for the specific rules there. You've mentioned some countries, there are many more with many more rules. In the US, for example, ATMs are usually not free even in bank branches and you should expect different fees depending on the bank and the location.
There are maps (e.g.: ATM locators by Visa, Mastercard), but I'm not sure how reliable they are when it comes to fees. I know for a fact that they may not be exhaustive.

Note that ATM operators usually get a fee from the card issuer for each withdrawal, who will then either pass it on (with a margin) to the cardholder or integrate it in their costs (and thus in subscription fees or interest rates or however else they make money). For a long time they were enough to pay for the ATM service (or the banks who operated them saved enough by using ATMs instead of people to dispense cash), but apparently this is no longer the case and we now get those additional fees.

@jcaron in many countries there are no ATM fees as the result of either government regulation, or interbank agreements. Foreigners may not be covered by either, nor private ATMs (hence the difference the OP mentioned between bank-owned ATMs and others). These are not new "additional" fees, they have always been there, it's just more people travel and there are more non-bank ATMs now, so more people are exposed to them.
